# Pattern for filtering files with multiple combined extensions

Tags: php, regex

How to construct a regex to match

```
qwerty.html
```

but not

```
qwerty.php.html
```

or any combined extension. I've "created" this : `"/(?!\..*)\.html$/"` which returns 0. How to make it work?

This is the code that I have:

```
$regexIterator = new RegexIterator(
    new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path)),
    /(?!\..*)\.html$/
);
$files = (iterator_to_array($regexIterator));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following regexp

```
^([^.]*)\.[^.]*$
```

It match strings which contains only one dot - example [here](https://regex101.com/r/0zPLs4/3) - explanation

- `[^.]*` match any character except dot

For match only html files use `^([^.]*)\.html*$`

Comment: FYI 1) `{1}` is redundant and is better removed. 2) `[^.]*` will match any extension, OP needs to match `html`.

Comment: I've made an update, with the code that I have. This returned all of the files, including *.php :(

Comment: @Bakudan for html files only use `^([^.]*)\.html*$`

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski yes, this was the thing I wanted to achieve. Could you please add it to the answer.

Comment: @Bakudan I add it on the bottom

Answer (score 0):

The `(?!\..*)\.html$` pattern matches `.html` at the end of the string only if there is no `.` immediately to the right of the current location (the `(?!\..*)` negative lookahead enforces this restriction). Note `.*` at the end of the lookahead pattern makes no difference. As `\.` in `\.html` requires a dot to be right there where `(?!\..*)` prohibits it, the pattern will never match any string.

You may use

```
'~^[^.]*\.html$~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5aG5Hp/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^.]*` - a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) matching 0+ chars other than `.`
- `\.html` - a `.html` substring
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

You regex doesn't work because you are saying that the next characters shouldn't include period in them (i.e. `(?!\..*)`) but immediately you say they should (i.e. `.html`).

The only solution that would be acceptable is the following:

```
\.\w+\.html$(*SKIP)(*F)|\.html$
```

Regex [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/x9U6lQ/1)

Regex breakdown:

- `\.\w+\.html$` Match a `.html` file that has a preceding extension name
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` Throw it away
- `|` Or
- `\.html$` Match a `.html` file that has not a preceding extension

This doesn't allow `.{alphanum + _}.html` like:

- `.php.html`
- `.mp4.html`
- `.j_p_g.html`

But doesn't mess up with different file names at the same time and allows patterns like below:

- `a.file.name@user.html`